# c++ general interpretation q

Tags: c++

This is homework so i don't want you to give me the answer, i'd just like to know exactly what it is my instructor wants me to do?

Given the string pointer and the variable sz below, use them to dynamically create an array of size sz.

```
string * sp;
int sz=5;
```

Answer (score 2):

He wants you to write a line of code that dynamically allocates an array of pointers to strings of size `sz`.

```
string * sp;
int sz = 5;
// put a line of code here that allocates the array
```

Comment: so is "string array[sz];" the answer?? or am i still missing the point? im not sure what i need to do with the string *sp;

Comment: @user1145538: That would not be a dynamic allocation. Your teacher needs a dynamic allocation, *Hint:* `new`().

Comment: You're supposed to store the address of the array in the string pointer.

Comment: i hate to give up... but can i get one more hint before i trash this problem all together?

Comment: Do you know how to dynamically allocate an array in c++? The first hit on a google search for "dynamically allocate array c++" had the answer, though with an `l` where there should be a `;`. (What idiot decided to put two such similar looking characters so close together on the keyboard?)